# owl-crousel in ajax is not working

Tags: html, ajax, owl-carousel

This is what i tried to implement owl-crousel.`enter code here`
 anybody knows please help me. i tried so many times.
i dont know why its not working.so please help soon

```
  for (i = 0; i < splitimg.length; i++) {
                            // text += splitimg[i] + "<br>";
                            if (splitimg[i].length > 0) {
                                $('#img-galary').append('<a  class="item" rel="prettyPhoto"  href="admin/Vanue_Image/s/' + splitimg[i] + '"><img src="admin/Vanue_Image/s/' + splitimg[i] + '" width="300" height="150" ></a>');
                               var owl = $("#img-galary");
                                owl.owlCarousel({
                        items: data, //10 items above 1000px browser width
                        itemsDesktop: [1000, 5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
                        itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 3], // betweem 900px and 601px
                        itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0
                        itemsMobile: true, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
                        pagination: true

                    });
                                jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('#img-galary').html("");
                                $('#img-galary').append('<a   href="#"><img src="admin/Vanue_Image/Not-available.gif" height="80"  width="120" style="padding: 2px" ></a>');



                               // var div = document.getElementById('image-panel-defoult');
                                //var div1 = document.getElementById('video-galary');

                               // div.style.visibility = 'hidden'
                            }

                        }
```